# preg_match_all not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

What is wrong in following regex?

```
$source =
"Je (1200) recycler(s) hebben een totale opslagcapaciteit van 24.000.000. 
In het bestemmingsveld [2:188:7] zweven 0 metaal en 5.000 kristal in de ruimte. 
Je hebt 0 metaal en 5.000 kristal opgehaald."


echo $source;
$regex  = 'Je \(([0-9.]*?)\) recycler(s) hebben een totale opslagcapaciteit van ([0-9.]*?). ';
$regex .= 'In het bestemmingsveld \[2:188:7\] zweven ([0-9.]*?) metaal en ([0-9.]*?) kristal in de ruimte. ';
$regex .= 'Je hebt ([0-9.]*?) metaal en ([0-9.]*?) kristal opgehaald.';

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/' . $regex . '/i', $source, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Is your input on several lines like in the example? Also, your digits should be captured with `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*`, not `[0-9].*?`_

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I think you - at least for one thing - need to escape the periods in some of the groups. ([0-9.]*?) should be ([0-9\.]*?) -- The dot otherwise collects all characters, and then there's really no point in having 0-9 (if that was the point, which I assume it isnt)

Comment: @MarkHünermundJensen, no, the `.` inside a character set matches only the literal `'.'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the parentheses in `recycler(s)` need a backslash. try: `recycler\(s\)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Je \(([0-9.]*?)\) recycler\(s\) hebben een totale opslagcapaciteit van ([0-9.]*?)\s+
\s+In het bestemmingsveld \[2:188:7\] zweven ([0-9.]*?) metaal en ([0-9.]*?) kristal in de ruimte.\s+
\s+Je hebt ([0-9.]*?) metaal en ([0-9.]*?) kristal opgehaald.
```

I quotes the parans in recycler(s), added some \s+ before and after the new lines and added a 's' modifier to the regex match